# How to parse the correct data with MySQL join and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables what I wish to join, but I simply can not get it to parse the data correctly.

The tables:
`b_kat_prod` contains product details, product SKU and category ID's
`b_product_sorter` contains the product SKU, category ID's and the sort value for sorting correctly.

```
CREATE TABLE `b_product_sorter` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `kat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subkat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ranking` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Data dump for tabellen `b_product_sorter`
--
INSERT INTO `b_product_sorter` (`id`, `kat_id`, `subkat_id`, `product_id`, `ranking`, `country`) VALUES
(227, 8, 0, '1902', 1, 'dk'),
(228, 8, 0, '1905', 2, 'dk'),
(229, 8, 0, '1908', 3, 'dk'),
(230, 8, 0, '1915', 4, 'dk'),
(231, 8, 0, '1809', 5, 'dk'),
(232, 8, 0, '1938', 6, 'dk'),
(233, 8, 0, '1940', 7, 'dk'),
(234, 8, 0, '1950', 8, 'dk'),
(235, 8, 0, '1906', 9, 'dk'),
(236, 8, 0, '1912', 10, 'dk'),
(237, 8, 0, '1918', 11, 'dk'),
(238, 8, 0, '1920', 12, 'dk'),
(239, 8, 0, '56110', 13, 'dk')

INSERT INTO `b_kat_prod` (`id`, `katref`, `prodref`, `subref`, `nyimport`, `sortering`, `nyhed`) VALUES
(18366, 8, '1906', 0, 0, 90, 1),
(18370, 8, '56110', 0, 0, 140, 0),
(18374, 8, '1920', 0, 0, 130, 0),
(18378, 8, '1918', 0, 0, 120, 1),
(18382, 8, '1938', 0, 0, 60, 0),
(18386, 8, '1940', 0, 0, 70, 0),
(18390, 8, '1902', 0, 0, 10, 0),
(18394, 8, '1905', 0, 0, 20, 1),
(18398, 8, '1915', 0, 0, 40, 0),
(18402, 8, '1908', 0, 0, 30, 0),
(18406, 8, '1950', 0, 0, 80, 0)
```

The code looks like this:

```
$get_products = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                            FROM b_kat_prod 
                            INNER JOIN b_product_sorter 
                                ON b_kat_prod.katref = b_product_sorter.kat_id 
                            WHERE b_kat_prod.katref = $_GET[id]");
```

Lets say that the `$_GET[id] = 45`. If I make a MySQL search for `45` in both `b_kat_prod` and `b_product_sorter`, it returns 55 results, however when I run the line of code above, it returns 3025 results (which equals 55*55). I only want it to return the 55 results - what am I doing wrong? I could group by product SKU but this messes up the sorting order.

Both tables can contain product SKU several times, as the products can be listed in several categories.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: You probably should be joining on the product SKU, not the category ID.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Maybe if you give a full details of the two tables somebody might be able to help

Comment: Your query just creates a cross product between all the rows in the two tables with the same category ID. There's nothing that says how to pair up specific rows with each other. SKU is the column that relates them. You probably shouldn't even have category IDs in both tables, that's a violation of normalization.

Comment: As a side note: mysql_* operations are unsecure and considered very bad practice, you should at minimum be using mysqli_* or better still PDO (PHP Data objects). You are also inserting raw $_GET requests directly into you query which basically leaves you wide open for an SQL Injection attack.

Comment: `mysql_*` isn't just insecure, it's been deprecated for more than a decade.

Comment: And nobody can help you if you don't post details of both tables.

Comment: @Barmar, You're absolutely right. I am able to solve it in only one table with one set of category id's and a sort column. I will place my entire data-set inside the same table and solve it that way.